# How to manage MySQL connections within MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Wehn I test the following PDO code, I could view the connections to MySQL in MySQL with `show processlist`, but how could I cut off one connection? Is there any other power tool for managing MySQL connection/etc other than command line?

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
// use the connection here


// and now we're done; close it
$dbh = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never worked with it, but there's [KILL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html) that looks like what you're looking for.

> Each connection to mysqld runs in a separate thread. You can see which threads are running with the SHOW PROCESSLIST statement and kill a thread with the KILL thread_id statement.
>
> In MySQL 5.0.0, KILL permits an optional CONNECTION or QUERY modifier: